# Count column in result set

Tags: sql, count, resultset

I have a result set like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I00kP.png)

what I need to do is count the times the acct_nmbr is in the result set to get something like this.
The end goal is to use a having clause to get rid of any account that appears more than once.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqTyv.png)

I have used:

```
select distinct Obj_id, acct_nmbr as Acct_nmbrr, datee ,count (acct_nmbrr) as "count"
```

but it is not returning the right results. I want to count only the result set.

Comment: How could the query execute?  You are mixing regular and aggregated columns without a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is using [row number](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-row_number/)

```
SELECT ObjID, AcctNmbr, Date, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNmbr ORDER BY ObjID) 
FROM sometable
```

And then remove the rows with `row_number > 1`, according to your logic.

Comment: @kyleisapenguin Hi, i'm glad it works. Can you mark my answer as 'accepted'?i

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED - I tried this on oracle, and get the results you want.  You probably have to tweak a bit for terradata, I am not familiar with it.   Basically, you create an in-line view for the aggregate, then join on acctnmbr with the main table

```
create table test (objid number, acctnmbr number, dateVal date );
insert into test values(1,111,sysdate);
insert into test values(2,111,sysdate+1);
insert into test values(199,222,sysdate);


select objid, test.acctnmbr,dateval,cntview.cnt
from test,
(
    select acctnmbr, count(*) cnt
    from test
    group by acctnmbr
) cntview
where cntview.acctnmbr = test.acctnmbr
```

Comment: The issue is the same account number will have multiple obj id's making distint not work/groupby doesn work. I am using Terradata... sorry for missing that.